# single membership providers within ASP.Net MVC 3 application sharing between 2 webapplications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharing, aspnetdb

We have 2 different mvc web applications running on single membership provider. I have put these 2 applications on the webserver and has the virtual path:
http://aa.svr1/app1
http://aa.svr1/app2

If user opens the app1 and app2 in seperate browsers it logs out the other aplication.
When user uses one application at a time, no issuess, concurrently used, its giving log off in one of the application.

I have put the machinekey in web.config file for app1 application and was working fine.
I have made new tfs release onto live server, now again back to the same situation that when app1, app2 browsed simultaneoulsy, logging off one of the application.

What could be causing this blocking sessions/behaving unexpectedly like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try explicitly specifying the path parameter of the authentication cookie:

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" path="app1" />
```

or simply use 2 different cookie names:

```
<forms name="app1auth" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
```

Comment: thanks Darin, you really saved my lots of time. I was able to fix by giving the <forms name> parameter. Manythanks again.

Comment: Hi Darin, Now my application is behaving very strangely, if the user 'A' logs in to the app1 website, automatically it redirects to another user 'B'. Could you please help me on this.